# Storing in Django Sessions

Tags: django, reactjs

I have a ReactJS component inside a Django template, where a user clicks on a checkout button, posts the `item_code` and gets redirected to checkout:

```
onCheckout = () => {
    fetch("/onCheckout/", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({'item': this.props.item_info.code})
      }).then(window.location.replace("/checkout"))
}
```

A Django view receives the request and stores it in a session.

```
def onCheckout(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        items = request.session.get('items', [])
        new_item = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))['item']
        items.append(new_item)
        request.session['items'] = items
```

I am having a issue with storing data in the session. After the first item gets stored correctly in the array, and I then checkout on a second item, the `items` array starts acting up:

```
(Pdb) items
['15130BC.ZZ.8042BC.01']
(Pdb) new_item
'5213G-001'
(Pdb) items
['15130BC.ZZ.8042BC.01']
(Pdb) items
['5213G-001']
```

If I try to access `request.session['item']` from any other view function, I get a KeyError.

I am fairly new to Django, any help would be appreciated. Also, I would like to know if there are better alternatives to accomplish the above.

**Sessions Config**

```
settings.SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'
settings.SESSION_CACHE_ALIAS = 'default'
settings.CACHES = {'default': {'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache'}}
```

Comment: Is there a login or some other account activity between the successive checkout operations? What is your session length?

Log `request.session.session_key` between successive requests - this should NOT change. If it changes, there's something wrong with the way your React app is contacting Django.

Comment: The `session_key` doesn't change, but when I try accessing `request.session['item'] from a different view function, I am getting a KeyError

Comment: Isn't the key `items` (plural)?

Comment: Thats what I meant, my mistake: `items = request.session.get('items', [])`

Comment: It returns an empty array

Comment: What is your session engine and cache backend? The value of `settings.SESSION_ENGINE`, `settings.SESSION_CACHE_ALIAS`. and `settings.CACHES`

Comment: @rtindru Updated my question with session config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some reading on change detection for Django sessions: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/sessions/#when-sessions-are-saved

Based on your code, it appears to me that the change detection should happen. However, let's try to brute force this, can you add the following line as the last line of your code: `request.session.modified = True` - see if this fixes your issue?

#### Update: some basic checks

Can you verify the following

Check if your db backend is configured priestly

> If you want to use a database-backed session, you need to add 'django.contrib.sessions' to your INSTALLED_APPS setting. Once you have configured your installation, run manage.py migrate to install the single database table that stores session data.

Check if your session Middleware is enabled

> Sessions are implemented via a piece of middleware. The default settings.py created by django-admin startproject has SessionMiddleware activated. To enable session functionality, edit the MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES setting and make sure it contains 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware'.

#### Update 2: Test the session

Maybe modify a style existing endpoint as follows and see if you are able to store values and persist them in session :

```
test_keys = request.session.get('test_keys', [])
test_keys.append(random.randint())
request.session['test_keys'] = test_keys
return Response(request.session.get('test_keys', []))
```

You should see that each time you hit the api, you get a list with one new integer in it in addition to all past values. Lmk how this goes.

Comment: You are positive of the following?
- The session IDs are the same between requests
- There is no middleware or anyone else changing the session values
- Your session expiry is set to a non-zero long enough value

Comment: Sessions in db table are being set for two weeks. Same session id. No middleware I am aware of. Session sits in db with a `session_data` field.

Comment: Hmm... This is super strange. Do you have multiple databases configured in your project? Or a separate db for reads?
Can you check the db value after your post request to see if the writes are happening as expected?

Comment: I was thinking it might be related to the @csrf_exempt decorator I'm using, would that make sense?

Comment: sessions and session middleware configured in settings, as well as db

Comment: Did you get a chance to check the session value in db to see if the writes are happening?

Comment: Csrf exempt shouldn't matter. Do you have a simple api endpoint you can test. Maybe a user api. Just pick a random key and random append to eliminate bad configuration of session as the reason.

Comment: last time i checked, writing to db was working, and getting updated. i have another api endpoint with csrf_exempt and its working fine.

Comment: oh i see your update, will check when i get back to work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171706/discussion-between-avremel-kaminetzky-and-rtindru).